# How can I easily benchmark my laptop and compare with others?

Tags: linux, performance, benchmarking

I came across Phoronix Test Suite because it was the only one I found on the internet which integrate your results with others (openbenchmark.org). However, besides it presents itself as an easy tool, it wasn't obvious to me. I started by running the `smallpt` test, but after 40 minutes I suspended it as I didn't know how much it would take.

I also thought about running the `pts/cpu` suite but it looked like it needed several dependencies, disk storage, and time running.

---

Then I took a look at `sysbench`, which seems a lighter tool. It is what I was really looking for. However, I can't compare my results with other machines. It would be interesting to upload those results and check that your hardware performance matches other machines with the same hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[PC Mark](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/pcmark) does exactly what you're requesting. Use 3Dmark for gaming benchmarks.